# Can't boot 16.04 after installing alongside Windows 7 (dual boot)

Tags: boot, 16.04, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 via burned CD on a new laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad) with Windows 7 installed.  I chose to partition the hard drive the default way (~50/50 split) for a dual boot solution and generally accepted defaults during installation.

When I boot the machine, it goes straight to Windows.  Booting from the CD indicates Ubuntu is indeed installed.  I hold shift during boot but no Grub loader comes up.  I've gone into the BIOS and checked for various fast boot options to disable but none really appeared (though I disabled a fast something or other for power from Intel, but that probably wasn't relevant).  It loads both UEFI and Legacy and the default was to boot from Legacy first; I changed that to boot from UEFI first to no effect.

I've also tried to do the Grub2 solution: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu boot-repair`, etc. (I did it a few times.) I get an error:

> The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

I tried following the instructions but didn't get anywhere.  Is the default ISO from Ubuntu's website not 64-bit?  Is there something else I should be looking at?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: File name of the iso I downloaded is ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.  Seems to suggest a 64 bit file.

Full error message is:
"The current session is in Legacy mode.  Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session.  This will enable this feature.  For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode."

Comment: The problem is the UEFI+Legacy mix up and the fact that you installed Windows 7 (Legacy) and Ubuntu (UEFI) in different modes.

Comment: @Michael "amd64" indicates 64-bit (AMD) architecture. "i386" indicates 32-bit (Intel) architecture.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Thank you all.   I'm away from that computer now but was able to boot into it once after removing the option to boot into Legacy in the BIOS and reinstalling Ubuntu over the same partition.  Grub loaded.  I'll have time again tomorrow to check again to see if there are any additional issues.    ..... not sure how to add a carriage return on mobile.  .... so new comment...

Comment: Rod, I can reproduce the issue if that would be helpful to the community but I apologize that I did not follow your advice prior to working my solution.  I am still curious why the "both" option caused an error and would love to see Ubuntu better able to detect these settings for install, if possible.  First  impressions for new users matter a lot and these are the sorts of things that might drive folks away.